# keep C# datetime local time between json and Web api?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have problem when I have datatime  in json object it will convert it to UTC time zone in C# dateTime just want to ask how to keep local time?can I set time zone  property in web.config file or geter or setter because I have to may object have day and time? 
this is class example ?

```
public class Patient
{
    public long RecordId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date 
      {
          get; 
          set;
      }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

update I tried to use getter and setter to fix I have this exception `{Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}`

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("api/postpatientform")]
public HttpResponseMessage PostPatientForm(PatientViewModel form)
{
    using (var db = new AthenaContext())
    {
        try
        {
            var form2 = Mapper.Map<Patient>(form);
            db.Patient.Add(form2);
            db.SaveChanges();

            var newId = form2.RecordId;
            foreach (var activity in form.PatientActivities)
            {
                activity.PatientId = newId;

                db.NonPatientActivities.Add(Mapper.Map<PatientActivity>(activity));
            }
            db.SaveChanges();

        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                    eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            throw;
        }
    }

    return Request.CreateResponse<Patient>(HttpStatusCode.Created, null);
}
```

Comment: Which method/library are you using for json serialization?

Comment: we aren't using  json serialization just Web Api to json object to poco object c#?

Comment: You made a recursive call. Create a separate property to for conversion. Or extract it to a different place

Comment: What input are you giving Web API? It should be determined by that.. For example:
`2015-08-18T17:30:31` is `Unspecified`, 
`2015-08-18T17:30:31Z` is `Utc`, and
`2015-08-18T17:30:31+03:00` is `Local`

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: @ZacCharles value from from javascript  'Tue Aug 18 2015 10:40:56 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)'

Comment: anyone come here maybe this answer would be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55436413/1538014

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can change your serializer settings to use the JSON.net serializer :

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = 
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
        DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Unspecified,
    };
```

> There is also various date format you can choose from : [DateTimeZoneHandling](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/DateTimeZoneHandling.cs)
>
> ```
> /// <summary>
> /// Specifies how to treat the time value when converting between string and <see cref="DateTime"/>.
> /// </summary>
> public enum DateTimeZoneHandling
> {
>     /// <summary>
>     /// Treat as local time. If the <see cref="DateTime"/> object represents a Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), it is converted to the local time.
>     /// </summary>
>     Local = 0,
>
>     /// <summary>
>     /// Treat as a UTC. If the <see cref="DateTime"/> object represents a local time, it is converted to a UTC.
>     /// </summary>
>     Utc = 1,
>
>     /// <summary>
>     /// Treat as a local time if a <see cref="DateTime"/> is being converted to a string.
>     /// If a string is being converted to <see cref="DateTime"/>, convert to a local time if a time zone is specified.
>     /// </summary>
>     Unspecified = 2,
>
>     /// <summary>
>     /// Time zone information should be preserved when converting.
>     /// </summary>
>     RoundtripKind = 3
> }
> ```

Comment: You beat me to it. Here's the official documentation: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDateTimeZoneHandling.htm

Answer (score 3):

You can configure this. See: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDateTimeZoneHandling.htm

Here's an example:

```
public void Config(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();

    var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
    jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;

    app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime to convert to the wanted timezone.

Checkout this method:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770(v=vs.110).aspx