# How to convert using date pipe from utc to local datetime in angular?

Tags: angular

How to convert using date pipe from utc to local datetime?

From what I able to find is the opposite. from local to utc. but I looking for utc to local datetime

Comment: Would this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46490538/angular-4-date-pipe-utc-time-to-local-time-how-to-tell-angular-the-current-ti?r=SearchResults

Comment: No. I want if possible to use the pipe date from angular. not create my own

Answer (score 0):

If you want all date-pipes in your application to use local timezone, you just have to modify your `app.module.ts` like this (I do it for Germany as an example):

1. Add following imports (instead of DE, use yours):

```js
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeDe from '@angular/common/locales/de';
```

2. Then register your localeID before the @NgModule: `registerLocaleData(localeDe);`
3. Declare it in the providers-array of the module:

```js
providers: [
   {
     provide: LOCALE_ID,
     useValue: 'de-DE',
   }
]
```