# Date value gets saved differently when client and server time zones are different

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, momentjs

My AngularJS client passes the date value in epoch milliseconds to my server which uses C#.NET. My client and server resides in different time zones. I am passing the date value from client side as following which returns the epoch milliseconds:

```
var date = $scope.date.getTime()
```

If I had a date selected from my client as '***Tue Jan 16 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)***' the epoch value corresponds to ***1516041000000***

But when I pass this epoch to my server side the GMT/UTC time,i.e, ***Monday, January 15, 2018 6:30:00 PM*** is getting saved to my database.

I was trying to pass the GMT offset to my server via my API header and add the offset value to the UTC time. But this causes issues when there is daylight saving since the offset is different for various date values.

```
DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var savedDate = epoch.AddMilliseconds(long.Parse(passedDateEpoch)).AddMinutes(ClientGmtOffset);
```

Is there any way to save the entered exact date in server database using the epoch time value itself. I don't want any time part or incorrect dates to be saved into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Use can speciafy the time unspecified in webapiconfig file For more info Like[[keep C# datetime local time between json and Web api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074667/keep-c-sharp-datetime-local-time-between-json-and-web-api])

You can specify as below so that to avoid the time conversion from server side

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);
            //subhash
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { action = RouteParameter.Optional, id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();


            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Unspecified;

            config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new CustomExceptionHandler());
        }
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
double dateFromClient = double.Parse("1521707203364");
var savedDate = (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).AddMilliseconds(dateFromClient);
```

But I think that is better to save Unix Timestamp (e.g. 1521707203364) at the DB, then when you return it to the client, the client parse it again and get the correct Date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code in the serverSide

```
 public struct DateTimeWithZone
{
    private readonly DateTime utcDateTime;
    private readonly TimeZoneInfo timeZone;

    public DateTimeWithZone(DateTime dateTime, TimeZoneInfo timeZone)
    {
        var dateTimeUnspec = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
        utcDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateTimeUnspec, timeZone); 
        this.timeZone = timeZone;
    }

    public DateTime UniversalTime { get { return utcDateTime; } }

    public TimeZoneInfo TimeZone { get { return timeZone; } }

    public DateTime LocalTime
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utcDateTime, timeZone); 
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return date from frontend like this

var date = new Date();

var isoDate = date.toISOString()